# Groovy Eval, why this doesn't work?

Tags: groovy

i have this simple code

```
def values = [foo:5, bar:6]  

def result = Eval.me("p", values, "${p.foo}+${p.bar}")
```

why it doesn't work ?

i get a:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: p for class: ConsoleScript7
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Strings in your Groovy expression aren't surrounded with double quotes, so Groovy isn't treating them as a GString with expression support.  Adding escaped double quotes around the expression and escaping the `$` will give you a working result.

```
Eval.me("p", values, "\"\${p.foo}\"+\"\${p.bar}\"")
```

Also, you could to one of the following, depending on if you want to output a String or and integer value:

```
Eval.me("p", values, "p.foo.toString()+p.bar.toString()")
```

or

```
Eval.me("p", values, "p.foo+p.bar")
```

Comment: Thanks, my code was wrong,  what i want is the last example that you wrote.